# laravel 5 ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i had a user list form in laravel. so i want when i click the table row, it automatically load the user details from database without redirecting. i've heard about ajax. but i have no idea how to use it in laravel..

i want to make like this [image]

[image]

but without redirecting page..

```
$("tr").click(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: $(this).data("href"),
          dataType: "text",
          success : function(data) {
                      $('#details-container').load(data)
                    }
        });
    });
```

does it supposed to be like this? but how did i get the data from database? i have no idea. please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same in Laravel as in "native" PHP. With your Ajax request your are able to send and asynchronous request, and refresh just a little part of your website, so you dont need to reload your whole page.

If you want to make it work with laravel, you should:

1. create a route for your requests

   ```
   Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
   {
       // So all your GET requests with any user id goes to this script (in routes.php) 

       // here you should load your user information, maybe with ORM

       $user = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();

      // Build any HTML snippet, or build JSON data (and build the information in Javascript on your page)

    //return here JSON / or html
    $data = array() -> containts information for the blade template
    return view('users.information', $data);

   });
   ```
2. Your AJAX request returns now JSON / or HTML, append it to your site where you would like to show it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your page structure will be like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr data-details-link="http://your-domain/user/{user-id}/details">
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### The page with the table, should have this jQuery codes:

```
$('table tr').on('click', function (event)
{
  event.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  // not necessary but you should show a loading here

  $.ajax({
    url: $this.data('details-link')
  })
    .success(function (response)
    {
      // the `response` variable is HTML code. Insert it into a modal.
    });
});
```

#### Your route:

```
...
Route::get('user/{id}/details', [ 'uses' => 'UserController@details' ]);
...
```

#### Your `UserController` method:

```
public function details($id)
{
  $user = \App\User::find($id);

  if (!$user)
    abort(404);

  return view('user.details')->with('user', $user);
}
```

**Your `user/details.blade.php` should have the HTML that will be send as the AJAX response.

Comment: emm sorry. i still dont understand what do mean about modal, in the function?

Comment: An example to modals would be the following link. Click *Launch demo modal*. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo